# jquery-ui tabs - adding tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

I have a list of items shown in one tab and I want to be able to click on one of the items and open a new tab and show its details on the new tab. I am adding the new tab by doing the following:

```
$(".btn-opener").click(function(){

$('#tabs').tabs('add', 'http://localhost/GetItem/' + $(this).attr('href'), "View Details");

}
```

My problem is that the url is actually a service endpoint returning JSON. I want to be able to apply a js template to the returned data. How do I do this? Do I need to hook into the tab's load event?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm going to solve this by adding a div with the HTML I need into the tab conainer, and then using its id to set the fragment of the new tab. For example:

```
$('.btn-opener').click(function () {

    var $this = $(this),
        itemID = $this.data("item-id");

            $.get("http://localhost/GetItem/" + itemID,

                function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                    var html = Mustache.to_html($("#item-template").html(), data);                          

                    $("#tabs").append('<div id="' + id + '">' + html + '</div>');
                    $('#tabs').tabs("add", "#" + id, $this.text());

                },  
                "json"
            );

            return false;
        });
```

I will wait to see if anyone comes up with a better solution before marking this as the answer.